# Trigger action when new post is insert in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

My question is,

Is there any filter or action that trigger when new post is insert in database..?

The reason behind it is I want to add key in post meta when new post is insert from **admin side**.

I got Action called `"save_post"` but after refer [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) .This action trigger in **created and update** post.
but I only want to add meta key when post is created **not at update time**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`wp_insert_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post) so you will get `post_id` as soon as post inserted and you can then use that to add `meta_key`.

If you are not using `wp_insert_post` and want to use `action` then you can simply put below code :

```
if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
    return;
```

which means that if you are updating the post, then it will return back from `function`.

**EDITED**

**Method-1** to achieve it.

You can simply check with the `get_post` method that post is there or not.something like below:

```
add_action('save_post', 'check_for_post_in_database');
function check_for_post_in_database($post_id) {
    //check if the post is in the database or not with get_post( $post_id ) == null 
    if( get_post( $post_id ) == null ) {
        //your code to add meta
    }
}
//You can do same thing with publish_post
```

**Method-2** to achieve it.

```
add_action('publish_post', 'check_for_meta_in_database');
function check_for_meta_in_database($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $your_meta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_key', true);
    if( empty( $your_meta ) && ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_key', 'meta_value');
    }
}
```

But as you said there are many meta there, this method will be bit long.

**Method-3** to achieve it.

You can do as **rnevius** suggested which is the one even I would opt. Its like :

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'check_transition_and_then_add_meta', 10, 3 );
function check_transition_and_then_add_meta( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) { 
    if ( ( 'draft' === $old_status || 'auto-draft' === $old_status ) && $new_status === 'publish' ) {
        add_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_meta_key', 'your_meta_value');
    }
}
```

or else you can do it with `draft_to_publish` like:

```
//as rnevius suggested {$old_status}_to_{$new_status}
add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'add_meta_when_status_change' );
function add_meta_when_status_change() { 
     add_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_meta_key', 'your_meta_value');
}
```

You can refer [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) for more information about post transition.

Comment: @vrajesh see my updated answer. During testing, I found method 1 is not working for me. But I would suggest you to go with **method-3**.

Comment: It feels nice to help specially if he is from gujarat ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`draft_to_publish`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions).

> An `{old_status}_to_{new_status}` action will execute when a post transitions from `{old_status}` to `{new_status}`. The action is accompanied by the `$post` object.

Comment: is it wordpress 'action'?

Comment: Yes...did you click the link?

Comment: Hey when I used add_post_meta() function, it cretes many entry in wp_post_meta :(..........

Comment: please check jsfiddle.net/7dmqwdtg