# How to insert new hidden postmeta on a published post ? WordPress

Tags: wordpress, insert-update

there are a hundred posts to update the postmeta if I do manually. I try to find a way to insert new postmeta based on the `post_type` and category. I try this:

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'category'
];

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if( $query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        add_post_meta($query->post->ID, '_meta_key', meta_value, true);
        add_post_meta($query->post->ID, '_meta_key2', meta_value2, true);
        add_post_meta($query->post->ID, '_meta_key3', meta_value3, true);
        add_post_meta($query->post->ID, '_meta_key4', meta_value4, true);
        add_post_meta($query->post->ID, '_meta_key5', meta_value5, true);
    }
}
```

and it is not working. is there anyway to achieve ?

OK I found the answer here [Trigger action when new post is insert in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950781/trigger-action-when-new-post-is-insert-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Use `update_post_meta` function to update post meta values.

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'category'
];

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if( $query->have_posts() ) { 
           $query->the_post();

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        update_post_meta($query->post->ID, '_meta_key', meta_value, true);
        update_post_meta($query->post->ID, '_meta_key2', meta_value2, true);
        update_post_meta($query->post->ID, '_meta_key3', meta_value3, true);
        update_post_meta($query->post->ID, '_meta_key4', meta_value4, true);
        update_post_meta($query->post->ID, '_meta_key5', meta_value5, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working. and also there's no the _meta_key on the db. so, it can not update.

Comment: _meta_key means your custom fields name, Replace _meta_key with your desire custom field name.

Comment: Thanks @Gufran. at last, i've found the anwser how to properly add new meta. and yes i do your suggestion using update_post_meta. Thanks. :)

Comment: Welcome :) How did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

**Add meta value when post or page or custom post published.**

```
function save_post_meta( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    if ( "your post name" != $post_type ){ return;}

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', 'value');
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_post_meta', 10, 3 );
```